# Undoing a command in terminal?

Tags: git, terminal, command

So I was using terminal to create and move some files around in my folder on my Mac.

I wanted to move 4 text files (Atom) from a directory called `my_profile_project` to my `moodykhedr3.github.io` folder (on my computer, so that I would commit and push to git afterwards).

Apparently, I did it wrong. And what happened was, it renamed all the files I was trying to move to `moodykhedr3.github.io`, which made all the text in the files the same.

I had a few HTML and one CSS that styled them. Really need to get this back. Any suggestions? I was wondering if I can undo commands in terminal.

Answer (score 2):

BLUF: Yes, but very difficult and not a built in function.

Lets break down what happened by looking at the man pages for mv:

> As the rename(2) call does not work across file systems, mv uses
>   cp(1)
>        and rm(1) to accomplish the move.  The effect is equivalent to:
>
> ```
>        rm -f destination_path && \
>        cp -pRP source_file destination && \
>        rm -rf source_file
> ```

Well we know the cp worked, you have the destination file.  I believe your goal is to get the original file, so it's the last rm that you want to undo.

So for rm - The rm utility removes symbolic links, not the files referenced by the links.  This is why the rm documentation says

> Note that if you use rm to remove a file, it is usually possible to
>   recover the contents of that file. If you want more assurance that the
>   contents are truly unrecoverable, consider using shred.

From the documentation we find that rm actually calls unlink(1) or unlink(2)

> When the utility is called as unlink, only one argument, which must
>   not
>        be a directory, may be supplied.  No options may be supplied in this sim-
>        ple mode of operation, which performs an unlink(2) operation on the
>        passed argument.

So for unlink:

> unlink() deletes a name from the file system. If that name was the
>   last link to a file and no processes have the file open the file is
>   deleted and the space it was using is made available for reuse. If the
>   name was the last link to a file but any processes still have the file
>   open the file will remain in existence until the last file descriptor
>   referring to it is closed.
>
> If the name referred to a symbolic link the link is removed.
>
> If the name referred to a socket, fifo or device the name for it is
>   removed but processes which have the object open may continue to use
>   it.

With that understanding - you want to basically relink a file to the inode number before that space is reused.  This isn't easy.  Here is a link for a similar discussion.  If you successfully accomplish this, you will have two files, the one you moved to, and the original.

https://serverfault.com/questions/168909/relinking-a-deleted-file

Comment: Thank you for the response. I actually figured it out! Since the files were open in atom, I pressed CTRL+Z in each one until it returned to it's original format. Then I copied all inofo into on text file, deleted the old files, then made new  ones and saved.  THANK YOU!